# Enviar un email con pdf en laravel 8 con la librería de barryvdh

Tags: laravel, email, dompdf

Cuando quiero mostrar datos en el PDF y mandarlo por email es cuando me da un error
pero si mando el email sin poner prueba si llega a mi email
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el error que me sale a veces me sale variable indefinida
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
EL código y los errores van como texto. La gente que voluntariamente ayuda es buena compilando en sus máquinas, no en su cabeza, así que debes ayudar a que se pueda replicar tu problema. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).